# Absolute value function in Rust

Tags: function, macros, rust, absolute-value

In this elementary Rust program a function calculates the absolute value of an integer, and main() helps in completing a statement with the result:

```
fn main() {
    let value = abs(-4);
    println!("{}.", value);
}

fn abs(x: i32) -> i32 {
    print!("The abs value of {} is ", x);

    if x > 0 {
        return x;
    } else {
        -x
    }
}
```

Is there a way to print correctly the whole statement "The abs value of... is..." into the abs() function? I tried unsuccessfully with

```
println!("The abs value of {} is {} ", x, x);
```

This always prints the value of the x parameter (e.g. -4, -4) so it's not correct.

And with

```
println!("The abs value of {} is {} ", x, abs(x));
```

But here, for some reason, Rust is not happy with recursion, gives a warning at compilation and then doesn't run the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e1161f4dedb794dcf09fa2cc9379f590&version=stable) to avoid recursion:

```
fn main() {
    let value = abs(-4);
    println!("{}.", value);
}
fn abs(x: i32) -> i32 {
    let y = if x >= 0 { x } else { -x };
    println!("The abs value of {} is {} ", x, y);
    y
}
```

Output:

```
The abs value of -4 is 4
4.
```

---

There are built-in `.abs()` method for primitive types e.g. 
[i8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i8.html#method.abs), 
[i16](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i16.html#method.abs), 
[i32](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.abs), 
[i64](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html#method.abs), 
[i128](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i128.html#method.abs), 
[f32](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.abs), 
and [f64](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.abs):

```
assert_eq!(10i32.abs(), 10);
assert_eq!((-10i32).abs(), 10);
```

#### Overflow behavior

> The absolute value of `i32::min_value()` cannot be represented as an
>   `i32`, and attempting to calculate it will cause an overflow. This
>   means that code in debug mode will trigger a panic on this case and
>   optimized code will return `i32::min_value()` without a panic.

The following code, will panic in [debug](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95b6e62b07fa995cb788359f314a1327) mode (and returns `-128` in [release](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=32ab5f734d4c59f2bd6553d9a62ab0ec) mode):

```
fn main() {
    let a = -128_i8;
    println!("{}", a); // -128
    let b = a.abs();
    println!("{}", b); // -128
}
```

---

Since `abs(-2_147_483_648_i32)` is `2_147_483_648_u32`, you may return `u32` instead of `i32`:

```
fn abs(x: i32) -> u32 {
    if x >= 0 {
        x as u32
    } else if x == std::i32::MIN {
        2_147_483_648_u32
    } else {
        -x as u32
    }
}
fn main() {
    let value = abs(std::i32::MIN); // i32::min_value() // -2_147_483_648i32
    println!("{}.", value); // 2147483648
}
```

[Output](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=808c4fc5ca72d69863be36e55dd13e0f):

```
2147483648
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. At this point I can simply call abs(-4) from main and delete the "let value = " and the whole "println!" statement in main.

Comment: Yes: `fn main() {
    abs(-4);
}`

Answer (score 3):

The absolute value method is [already defined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.abs); you do not need to implement it yourself

```
fn main() {
    let value = abs(-4);
    println!("{}.", value);
}

fn abs(x: i32) -> i32 {
    let val = x.abs();
    println!("The abs value of {} is {}", x, val);
    val
}
```